# Storyteller.NET with NServiceBus fails to start the endpoint instance

Tags: .net, nservicebus, appdomain

I have a setup of StoryTeller with Storyteller csproj runner, so from my project folder I run this kind of script to open up the StoryTeller web application:

```
"..\..\packages\StorytellerRunnerCsproj.4.2.0\tools\StorytellerRunner.exe" open "..\..\MyTestProject" --culture en-US --app-domain
pause
```

Storyteller will go through the types in my project and load them into a separate AppDomain (as per the --app-domain option), like many testing frameworks do.

The problem I am having is that I want to send messages via NServiceBus within my tests. In order to do this, I first have to start a NServiceBus endpoint, like so:

```
var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration);
```

While the above code with the given endpoint configuration works fine on a normal console app, it gives the following error when running it in Storyteller:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Can't find any behaviors/connectors for t
he root context (NServiceBus.Pipeline.ITransportReceiveContext)
   at NServiceBus.PipelineModelBuilder.Build()
   at N
ServiceBus.StepRegistrationsCoordinator.BuildPipelineModelFor[TRootContext]()
   at NServiceBus.Pipeline`1..ctor(IBuild
er builder, ReadOnlySettings settings, PipelineModifications pipelineModifications)
   at NServiceBus.StartableEndpoint
.<Start>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runt
ime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.Handle
NonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Endpoint.<Start>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace
from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSucc
ess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at QPark.Cloud.Testi
ng.Shared.Messaging.MessageService.<StartEndpointAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\tfs\git\Repos\SystemTests\QPark.Cloud.Syste
mTests\QPark.Cloud.Testing.Shared\Messaging\MessageService.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location whe
re exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Syst
em.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.Compile
rServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

I am suspecting this has to do with the fact that Storyteller loads this code in another AppDomain, and somehow this breaks NServiceBus...

Comment: I find _"I want to send messages via NServiceBus within my tests"_ a bit challenging. Why would you use reliable messaging for short-lived unit test executions? Are you trying to replace your logs with message that are logged and reviewed/actioned in asynchronous manner? Could you please elaborate what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @SeanFeldman, I was not explicit enough in what I meant. I want to run end-to-end tests against actual system (so not unit tests but rather integration tests). This involves sending asynchronous messages between services.